# Removing keys/values from a JSONB object in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to adapt the [Audit trigger](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql) to use `JSONB` instead of `hstore`. This function stores all inserts/updates/deletes in a separate table.

The trigger has 2 interesting fields : `row_data` (contains the OLD.* values) and `changed_fields` (contains only the modified fields/values).

I have trouble converting this part.

In the original function, we have the following code :

```sql
audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*);
audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(NEW.*) - audit_row.row_data);
```

In my implementation, row_data and changed_fields are of type `JSONB`

In the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html), the "-" operator will match on keys only and I obviously need to match on both key AND value.

As an example, if the OLD value is this :

```
select jsonb_object('{field1,1,field2,a string,field3,TRUE}');
                      jsonb_object                       
---------------------------------------------------------
 {"field1": "1", "field2": "a string", "field3": "TRUE"}
```

and only `field2` was updated, I need to see this :

```
        ?column?        
------------------------
 {"field2": "a string"}
```

which I would get with this query :

```
select jsonb_object('{field1,1,field2,a string,field3,TRUE}')
       #- '{field1}'
       #- '{field3}';
```

Is there an elegant way to do this (like how it's done with hstore) or should I keep the hstore implementation and convert `changed_fields` to JSONB (with everything seen as text) ?

I could also loop on all fields in NEW and add them to `changed_fields` if a match could not be found but how to do this inside a function ?

Comment: Did you see this: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: No I didn't. This is the perfect solution (make it an answer if you want me to accept it).